# How to modify UI Grids gridoptions.data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using UI Grid for displaying large table (30-40 columns) and thousands of rows. I am getting my data through websocket which is basically json array. 
The Incoming data is in two parts, one is "add" array which contains rows which are directly pushed to $scope.gridOptions.data. Another part of incoming data is
 "edit" array which consists of rows which will replace/modify existing  $scope.gridOptions.data.

The Add part is pretty straightforward, just push to existing gridOptions.data array. But Edit part is tricky. Currenty I am looping through incoming array
 on gridoptions array. This is the worst but working solution, can there be a better way to do this?

I thought that using "indexOf" function on array, we can directly find the array index at which it can be modified. But as the UI Grid is angular based, all the three arrays 
(add, edit and scope.gridOptions) contain unique $$hashKey, so we can not use indexOf.

Can I get rid of $$hashkey by angular.toJson function without any side effect?

I have field to identify unique rows, can I replace it with $$hashKey by using something like 'track by' in UI grid?

here's my code:

```
  $scope.$on('test',function(event, data){ 

        $scope.add(data.ADD);

        $scode.edit(data.EDIT);


        $scope.$apply();

  });   


$scope.edit=function(data){

  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
     //var j = $scope.gridOptions.data.indexOf(data[i]);
     //$scope.gridOptions.data[j] = data[i];

     for(var j = 0; j < $scope.gridOptions.data.length; j++) {
         if(data[i].iRowID == $scope.gridOptions.data[j].iROWID ) {
             $scope.gridOptions.data[j] = data[i];

         }
     }
  }
};


$scope.add=function(data){

   for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

       $scope.gridOptions.data.push(data[i]);
   }
};
```